# Modem/Router/Networking Emulators

Tags: networking, router, modem

I'm looking for a decent source of modem/router emulators. Something along the lines of the following

- http://www.voiproblem.com/emulators/Netgear/
- http://www.voiproblem.com/emulators/Linksys/

The 2 above are ideal. But does anyone know of a source for the more obscure brands (Buffalo, Belkin, Zyxel etc).

I'm not 100% sure of the legality of these being published.. But would appreciate if anyone knew of similar sites!

The reason I'm asking is its just a pain when someone asks me to help them set up their new modem/router and I don't know what to tell them (I just dive in and try to look like I know my way around).

Edit: SU pressured me into setting up a bounty! Will let the bounty run out to give the highest voter(s) the rep.

Comment: Good question, this'll come in handy

Comment: @Ciaran, Linksys hosts their emulators on their own site as well: http://ui.linksys.com/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

D-Link

- http://www.dlink.com/us/en/support/faq/multimedia/cameras-and-surveillance/does-d-link-provide-an-emulator-simulator-for-my-device

Netgear

- http://firmware.netgear-forum.com/index.php?act=interface

Linksys

- http://ui.linksys.com/

DD-WRT v22, v23, v24beta & latest stable

- http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Web_Interface#Simulation
- http://www.dd-wrt.com/demo

Draytek

- http://www.draytek.com/user/SupportLiveDemo.php

Cisco/Pix (desktop install)

- http://www.gns3.net/

TP-LINK

- http://www.tp-link.com/en/support/emulators/

Notes:

- various emulators here: http://skyangel.wikidot.com/emulators
- Netgear seems to host emulators on their own site, but I can't find a central index: http://www.google.com/search?q=site:tools.netgear.com+simulators

Comment: Thats more what I was looking for. Thanks. Will reserve my accepted answer for a while

Comment: DD-WRT (v22,v23,v24): http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Web_Interface#Simulation

Comment: The D-Link one's gone down :( shame because it looked pretty comprehensive

Comment: Still works for me.  In case it does go down, mirror here: http://support.dlink.ca/faq/view.asp?prod_id=1457

Comment: Cisco IOS and PIX emulator: http://www.gns3.net/.  You have to download and install this.  Not your typical home routers, but just trying to be comprehensive.  Also a DrayTek: http://www.draytek.com/user/SupportLiveDemo.php, a little slow and buggy but workable.  I'll consolidate these links into my answer later...

Comment: hyperslug, it would be better if you edit your answer instead of adding links in the comments. It's easier to read that way.

Comment: @Nifle, done, just didn't want unnecessary bumps

Comment: Turned out to be an excellent answer :)

Comment: w00t, found another one http://www.tp-link.com/support/simulator.asp

Comment: http://www.dd-wrt.com/demo

Comment: readynas http://www.readynas.com/simulators/frontview/

Answer (score 5):

Heres another one:

- http://www.trendnet.com/emulators/

Here is a list of some from our friends at bestbuy. Never heard of some of these:

- http://geeksquadwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Router_Emulators

And the TP-LINK brand of router:

- http://www.tp-link.com/en/support/emulators/

Comment: I love these things. I do tech support for local isp. Some of our clients are static and these things are life savers trying to walk them through putting their static info in.

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite the answer you're looking for but it's what I've done in your situation before:

1. Set up a server which allows you to `ssh` in and set up a port forward.
2. Port forward from your server's `localhost` to the user's router.
3. `ssh` into your server and connect to the above forwarded port to access the routers web admin page.

This sounds like a lot of effort but it works really well and you can set up a simple package with [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to do all the above easily.

Let me know if you want more details.

Comment: I like this. But not quite what I'm looking for. Thanks for the help! +1

Answer (score 3):

At least for Linksys products, if you're worried about being legit, you can use:

http://ui.linksys.com/

Answer (score 3):

DSL Modems & Gatways, Many of which used By AT&T can be found here
http://skyangel.wikidot.com/modemguides